# hidden div doesn't appears where i want it to appear

Tags: java, html, jsp, visibility

This is my first on posting here. I hope you understand my question!

```
    <script  language="JavaScript">
       function setVisibility(id, visibility) 
       {
           document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
       }
    </script>   



    <% for(cart c: cart) {%>

    <td> ......</td>
    <td> ......</td>
    <td> ......</td>
    <td> ......</td>
    <td>
     <input type=button name=type value='Edit' onclick="setVisibility('DivQTY', 'inline');">                            

            <div id="DivQTY" style="display: none">
                 <input type="text" name="qty">
                 <form action="doEditCart.jsp?id=<%= c.getID() %>" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                 </form>
             </div>
    </td>
    <% }%>
```

This Shows a table and, in every row, shows a "Edit" button.

My problem here is that, if i press any "Edit" button in any row, "TextBox" and "Save" button appears only in the first row.

In this capture I pressed Edit in the fourth row.
How to show TextBox and Save button in the row that I pressed the edit button?

Thank you.

Comment: what is meaning of this line `<% for(cart c: cart) {%>` where `cart` is used two times. post your actual code.

Comment: it says that is too long. my actual problem here (i think so) it has to to with only html. i just want to show the textbox and the button in every row when i press edit.

Comment: i mean in the row that i pressed the edit button

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at below line where you are using same `id` for each `div`

```
<div id="DivQTY" style="display: none">
```

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document. Use different dynamic IDs for each element in HTML.

[HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) says ID must be document-wide unique.

Read more about it here [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: If the id is same then `document.getElementById(id)` will return just one element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` statement is creating different `<div>` elements with the same `id` attribute, what is not allowed.

As a solution, you could use the cart's id (`c.getID()`) as part of the div's id:

```
(...)
<input type=button name=type value='Edit' onclick="setVisibility('DivQTY<%=c.getID()%>', 'inline');">                            

    <div id="DivQTY<%=c.getID()%>" style="display: none">
(...)
```